# ListView ManipulationCompleted event doesn't work on phone

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have this code in a Windows 10 UWP application:

```
MyListView.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
MyListView.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) => x1 = (int)e.Position.X;
MyListView.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    x2 = (int)e.Position.X;
    if (x1 > x2)
    {
        DataController.PaneOpen(false);
    };
    if (x1 < x2)
    {
        DataController.PaneOpen(true);
    };
};
```

The `ManipulationCompleted` event doesn't work on phone in `ListView`. The code inside the handler never gets called.
It's working fine on PC, but doesn't work on phone. I don't understand why.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour and what is wrong on phone?

Comment: manipulationcompleted event dosn't work on phone in ListView. the code inside handler never be called.

Comment: OK, update this to your question, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `ListView` works on PC, we can scroll it by scrolling the wheel of mouse, but when it works on phone, there is no mouse device connected to a phone, we actually scroll the `ListView` through swiping.

A `ListView` control contains a `ScrollViewer` like this:
[image]

I think the problem is with this `ScrollViewer`, when it is on PC, it handles Scrolling and Manipulation events separately, but when it is on a phone, it can't differentiate the events of scrolling and manipulation.

In my view, this manipulation event can respond to Mouse device, but not to single finger touch. It is clearer if we test a `ListView` on Mobile Emulator and simulator, when you use `Single Point Mouse Input` of a phone emulator or `Mouse Mode` of simulator, the manipulation events  works fine, but when you use `Single Point Touch Input` of mobile emulator or `Basic Touch Mode` of simulator, it doesn't work. Interesting thing is, **the manipulation events actually still works fine on a mobile emulator when we use `Multi-Touch Input`**. More interesting thing is, the official docs of [Using manipulation events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#using_manipulation_events) says:

> If you don't have a touch-screen monitor, you can test your manipulation event code in the simulator using a mouse and mouse wheel interface.

So, it's supposed to work on a real phone. Since I don't have any device by now, I can't tell if it works fine on a real phone, I will update my answer after I test it on device.

**But**, we can still manipulate a `ListView` on a phone by handling the events of `Pointer` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" PointerCanceled="PointerExisted" PointerEntered="PointerEntered" PointerMoved="PointerMoved" PointerExited="PointerExisted">
```

Tested it, it works fine both on PC and phone.

**Update:**

Just tested on X1 Carbon, Lumia950, I found that the Manipulation event will be triggered using two fingers, the result is same as it was on mobile emulator.

Comment: Did you test `PointerMoved` and `PointerExited` with touches? I don't think they get raised at all.

Comment: Have tried your approach, but `Pointer` events don't raise in Simulator with `Basic Touch Mode` and on Emulator

Comment: @JustinXL, yes, and I just tested it again, they can get raised, but be careful with the `PointerExited` event for this scenario, if the `ListView` can be scrolled in the vertical direction, it should have a `Width` less than the device's width, or you can test a `ListView` control inside a `Pivot` control as a item, the `PointerExited` event will be raised. But thanks to you, I always handle `PointerCanceled` and `PointExited` events together, I tested them separately just for your question, `PointerCanceled` event doesn't work on Emulator by my side. And my emulator version is 10586.

Comment: @Ku6opr, they work fine by my side both on Emulator and simulator except `PointerCanceled` event, I also tested `PointerPressed` and `PointReleased` events, they can get raised too, my emulator version is 10586, did you focus on the `ListView` before you tested these events of it? I'm doubting myself if I tested `PointerCanceled` event in a wrong way....

Comment: Good solution. I already resolve my task by using a thin grid column at left side of screen and handling manipulationcompleted event on it.

Comment: What about finger moving? I need finger move event and release event, but on 10586 emulator `PointerMoved` event works completely wrong

Comment: @Ku6opr, do you want to capture finger moving horizontally or vertically?

Comment: horizontally on vertical list