# Manipulations on ListView's parent

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app

I want to let the user swipe on control that contains ListView.
Here is the example code:

```
<Border ManipulationMode="All"
        ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Items>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
        </ListView.Items>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="200" Height="50"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Border>
```

For some reason ManipulationDelta event is not raising on a phone. How can i solve this?

Comment: Tested your code, this problem only occur when testing on mobile emulator or simulator or device phone, not on PC, or local machine. Am i right?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very beginning I want to say, if there is no `Margin` on the `ListView` or no `Padding` on the `Border`, and there is no such size limit on both elements, the `ListView` in this scenario will fill the whole border and catch all the event first by default.

But [UIElement.ManipulationDelta event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationdelta.aspx) is a routed event. When you swipe on it, the `ListView` catches it, the meanwhile you didn't handle this event on `ListView`, so will this event bubble up to parent elements because it goes unhandled, then your `Border` as a parent elemtn can handle this event. This is why manipulations on ListView's parent can get fired on PC.

But why can't it get fired on mobile emulator? As I said, this swipe gesture is first caught by `ListView`, and a `ListView` control contains a `ScrollViewer` in it, this `ScrollViewer` will handle your swipe gesture as scrolling on mobile emulator, then won't `ListView` pass this event to its parent again like it on PC.

The difference between this event on PC and emulator is, the manipulation event can respond to Mouse device, but not to single finger touch. You can refer to [ListView ManipulationCompleted event doesn't work on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200600/listview-manipulationcompleted-event-doesnt-work-on-phone/35264256#35264256).

How to solve this problem? One very simple method is that you can give some space between `Border` and `ListView` like this `<ListView Margin="50">`, then you can catch this event outside the `ListView` on emulator, but this will break your original UI design. Another workaround method is like I said in that case, you can use `Pointer` event. Just tested it, when these events are on `ListView`'s parent, they can still get fired on emulator.